# Format and display array php

Tags: php

I have try to display array as readable format, but have some problem to display.

I have tried

```
foreach($results as $key => $value) {
    echo $key;
}
```

And this back me country name, also i have try with another foreach inside but can't back result as i need.

Array:

```
Array
(
    [Russia] => Array
        (
            [ru] => Array
                (
                    [0] => aaa
                    [1] => bbb
                    [2] => bbbfff
                )

        )

    [Brazil] => Array
        (
            [br] => Array
                (
                    [0] => aaa
                    [1] => bbb
                    [2] => bbbfff
                )

        )

    [Egypt] => Array
        (
            [eg] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ddd
                )

        )
)
```

Out should be like this

```
Russia
aaa
bbb
bbbfff

Brazil
aaa
bbb
bbbfff

Egypt
ddd
```

Comment: And what have you tried? Why not iterate over the inner keys of that array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've said that putting a nested `foreach` didn't work, but I can't see why it wouldn't?

Try the following code:

```
foreach($results as $country => $shorts) {
    //Echo the country name
    echo $country . "<br />";

    foreach( $shorts as $short=>$values ){
        //Print all the values for that country
        foreach( $values as $key=>$value ){
            echo $value . "<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `foreach` loop.

Loop over the array and get key, which is Country Name.

Again get the sub array with `current()` function and `implode()` it.

`current()` function returns current element that is first element in our case.

Code:

```
$arr['Russia']['ru'] = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'bbbfff'];
$arr['Brazil']['br'] = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'bbbfff'];
$arr['Egypt']['eg'] = ['ddd',];

if (! empty($arr)) {
 foreach ($arr as $code => $elem) {
  echo $code;
  echo "<br/>" . implode("<br/>", current($elem));
  echo "<br/><br/>";
 }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Russia
aaa
bbb
bbbfff

Brazil
aaa
bbb
bbbfff

Egypt
ddd
```

[Working example:](https://3v4l.org/SeekJ)

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
foreach($results as $country => $country_array) {
    echo $country;
    foreach($country_array as $key => $value) {
        echo $value;
        echo "<br>";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

You may change the `<br>` tag to the corresponding new-line tag in your enviroment, like `\n` in console.

Comment: Right, but make sure, you use different variables in the foreach.